# Yii Design - How to split the View logic?

Tags: php, templates, yii

MVC is a fairly new concept for me and I have just found myself doing something I am not quite sure would be considered 'a good practice'.

I have a controller `User` (extending from `CUserController`) that deals with all user relate actions. In this controller I have `actionLogin` that deals with login requests. Now in the process of login I need to display 3 different pages according to situation:

- Login form (enter username/password).
- Error message (if user details match but account is marked as blocked).
- Login successful page (if any new messages are associate with the account).

So far I have deal with it like that:

```
public function actionLogin(){
    ... perform some operations ...
    ... determine which page to display and set $scenario accordingly ...
    $this->render('login',array(
        'scenario'=>$scenario
    ));
}
```

And then in `login.php` (the view file):

```
... perform some common operations ...
switch($scenario){
    case "login":
        ...display login...
        break;
    case "error":
        ... display error ...
        break;
    .. etc. ...
}
```

Now this makes my view file show in fact entirely different pages (although closely related).

Would it be better to split my view into different pages (e.g. `login-form.php`,`login-error.php`,`login-success.php`) and render different ones in `actionLogin` according to the situation or is what I currently do a good way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option would be to try to fix the Yii interpretation of MVC design pattern, what I like to call ORM-Template-Adapter pattern.

Your issue stems from the fact, that, in proper MVC-inspired structure, the *Views* should be objects, responsible for **all** presentation logic and each capable of managing multiple templates.

The MVC variant which Yii actually strives to implement is MVP: model-view-presenter. The significant difference is that View in MVP is passive (which is not synonymous to "dumb template"). And you should stick to it.

I would recommend to create a class, that handles the representation of authentication. And have 4 templates:

- layout - the basic stuff, html part that won't change
- login - the form
- error - well .. guess what it does
- success

And then your new and improved view will decide, based on input from `User` <strike>controller</strike> *presenter*, which templates to combine.

... or you cold push more presentation logic onto your `User` "controller".

Comment: Thanks for your answer - very comprehensive :) I have taken this approach of having layout-template sets :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to not use MVC in MVC contest. Why? actionLogin is just action login. If you need a page for errors (... if you need ...), you could create actionError(). But I do not understand why. Often error are displayed in login page in a message. Think view as view (just html, css, js). Think model as data (array, query result). And think controller as a guy that take a view and render it with some source of data. Stop. You need a particular view with particular data? Well: just create that view, get that data. Last but not least, create you own controller for your mashup.

Comment: This is all done in my own controller.. Thanks for your explanation it gives me an idea of MVC. My action does perform several tasks at once to be honest, but it's either that or having hundreds of actions being defined and urls getting really messy. I have changed it slightly and it works :)

Comment: For errors stuff, take a look at this: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/

Comment: That will come in handy, thanks :) The only issue is that when user's account is inactive I really need a distinct looking message that can get quite long (reason for being deactivated, further instructions etc.) and thus I want to avoid displaying the error message on the same page as page as the login form.